# Replace a DL in all sites in SharePoint

Tags: 2007, permissions

I am required to update a Distribution List in all my MOSS 2007 SharePoint sites in a site collection. Is there a script or way I can do it?

Comment: can you be more specific? Distribution List i presume is a custom list? and what exactly do you want updating! could you give an example? from what im getting is you want to update all distribution lists in all sites from one site collection? so you have many Distribution Lists that exist on many sites under one site collection?

Comment: Here is my scenario. I have a Distribution List My-AD-DL which has users and this DL has access to various lists / libraries and sites in a Site Collection. Now for some reason, I have to replace this DL with MY-AD-DL2. But in the Site collection, I do not know where all is this DL used? Is there a way I can loop through all sites in the site collection and replace the DL My-AD-DL with My-AD-DL2 keeping the permissions same. Hope this clarifies my requirement.

Comment: Ok. So one thing I can see over after renaming my Active Directory DL is that, the old DL still works. However, is there a way I can rename my old DL with new DL name or rather synchronize the DL names across AD and SharePoint?